# Django: How to retrieve datetime as timezone-aware

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone

At one point in my program, I save a timezone aware (ISO8601 with Z) datetime:

```
param.updated=iso8601.parse_date(updated)
param.save
```

Later, I retrieve it to do a comparison:

```
if (newparam.update > Parameter.objects.get(id=id).updated):
....
```

Result:

```
TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I losing the timezone-awareness when I'm saving, or when I retrieve? How can I restore it?

Python 2.6.x, Django 1.3

Comment: Whoops, I lied. There was a sneaky extra "get_local_time" conversion in there.

Comment: Which database are you using? Most databases saves Timestamps as a long (number of milliseconds representing the data since an epoch.

Comment: SQLite. How can you tell? Using Squirrel, I see a formatted time - how do you see the raw contents?

Comment: still waiting for a solution that helps django 1.3 with timezones...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django 1.4 has support for timezones, check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#support-for-time-zones) out.

Comment: Oh, nice. Good to know. I probably can't immediately convert the project, but still. Also, after discovering that there was extra timezone conversion above, I later discovered that the timezone support is a bit broken anyway. Lesson: use pytz.timezone.localize(), not just datetime.astimezone()

Comment: -1 because upgrading django to 1.4 is impractical for most of the production cases; it involves a lot of time and resources(hence, money) on development side, esp. where the codebase is large enough; and sometimes it just can not be done, esp. when you do not have access/permissions to upgrade the server...

Comment: @Optimus untrue. we upgraded several very large django applications from 1.3 to 1.4 with no problems and no additional changes.

Comment: as a matter of fact I can not update the stack my company server is running on, (it involves a long complicated process of convincing a lot of people, and they might not even be convinced in the end...) and upgrading django is an overkill for just wanting to have a timezone aware site...